# How to bypass maintenance mode with external cron?

Tags: php, cron

I'm using crontab to run a php script loaded with `wp-load.php` with absolute path.

However, when I go to maintenance mode, the file can't run. I'm using Coming soon plugin.

Is there a way to exclude the file and run it even in maintenance mode?

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since the moment of the question, but maybe a solution will help someone in the future.

Just define IS_WP_CLI variable in the beginning of your script .

```
...
define('IS_WP_CLI', true); // Avoid maintenance mode
require_once HOME_PATH . '/wp-load.php';
...
```

If IS_WP_CLI defined -> maintenance mode will not be instantiated.

```
if (defined('IS_WP_CLI')) { return ; }
```

Now you can run cli scripts even if maintenance mode is active.

Comment: Where's the docs about 'IS_WP_CLI'? Do you have a link please?